# g++ ifstream matching error

Tags: c++, g++, ifstream

```
void FileIO :: openFile(const char* m_FileName,const char* m_FileMode);
```

I am getting error:

```
FileIO.cpp: In static member function ‘static void FileIO::openFile(const char*, const char*)’:
FileIO.cpp:12:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const char*&, const char*&)’
FileIO.cpp:12:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from FileIO.h:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:531:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:531:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}’
```

Comment: Mind showing your `openFile` ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

Comment: The error message says you're trying to call `std::ifstream::open` with two `char const*`.  There's no such function.

Comment: @Derek Not a very good page for a reference.  (There is at least one error in an example, of a sort which shows that the author doesn't really know iostreams.)

Comment: void File :: openFile(char* m_FileName, char* m_FileMode)
{
   if(!strcmp(m_FileMode(),"r"))
   {    
      m_FileInput.open(m_FileStatus,m_FileMode);
      if (m_FileInput == NULL)
      {
         cout<<"file does not exist";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      m_FileOutput.open();
   }
}

Comment: i want to feed the file name by char * ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::basic_ofstream::open` doesn't take *two* `const char*`s. (note: your subject says `ofstream` but from your comments it appears you're talking about `ifstream`).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

```
void open( const char *filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
void open( const std::string &filename,                                  
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in ); (since C++11)
```

The problem is the second, not the first argument.

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("hello", "rb" /*<-- problem, this is a const char* not flags.*/);
```

Instead, you need to pass it std::ios_base flags

```
ifstream ifs("hello", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
```

or

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("hello", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
```

--- EDIT ---

Looking at your comments following the post (why didn't you edit the post?) you are also trying to check for 'NULL'.

In C and C++ 'NULL' is a macro which is `#define`d as 0. So, checking for `NULL` *can* check for a null pointer, but it also can test for numeric values. If you want to check if the file opened, you will need to do:

```
m_FileInput.open("hello", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
if (!m_FileInput.good()) // checks if the file opened.
```

And you should try to use 'nullptr' instead of 'NULL' when possible.

Comment: but i want to take 'mode' as an input from user ...whther he wants to open the file in read mode or write mode ....like if he pree 'r' for read ..and 'w' for write...

Comment: Then use `fstream` instead of `ifstream` or `ofstream`, which are specializations for a specific direction. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use C's `FILE*` syntax to call a C++ open function. The mode (read/write/append) arguments are NOT string literals in C++ but enumerated values possibly ORed together.